# How can I specify a default location for xml content if no localised/localized version is available?

Tags: eclipse, localization, internationalization

This is a question about eclipse's cheat sheet functionality, though it applies more generally to the use of NLS in eclipse.

Let's say we originally have an eclipse cheat sheet, defined in the plugin.xml like so:

```
<cheatsheet
        category="com.example.myCategory"
        composite="false"
        contentFile="xmlContent/CheatSheet.xml"
        id="com.example.myCheatSheet"
        name="%CheatSheetName">
</cheatsheet>
```

This displays in English in all installations. If the user can read English, they can follow the instructions and learn.

Then we decide to translate the cheat sheet into French and Spanish, so we create translated copies of the content, and update the xml like so:

```
<cheatsheet
        category="com.example.myCategory"
        composite="false"
        contentFile="$nl$/xmlContent/CheatSheet.xml"
        id="com.example.myCheatSheet"
        name="%CheatSheetName">
</cheatsheet>
```

English, French and Spanish versions of the content are now in the following locations respectively:

```
nl/en/xmlContent/CheatSheet.xml
nl/fr/xmlContent/CheatSheet.xml
nl/es/xmlContent/CheatSheet.xml
```

The cheat sheet still displays correctly in all three locales (now in the local language), but if a user in a different locale (de, zh, it, jp...) tries to load the cheat sheet, they simply get an error saying the content cannot be found. This is less useful, as many users in these locales could still benefit from the English content.

Is there a way to set a default locale to be used in the case the content is missing, or must we make a copy for each of the hundreds of locales where a user could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is too just look for the path without the `nl/xx` prefix so in this case `xmlContent/CheatSheet.xml`.

The full rules are defined by the Eclipse [FileLocator.find](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FFileLocator.html&anchor=find(org.osgi.framework.Bundle,org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath)) API